# react return jsx from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, arrow-functions

From the FilterBydescription component of the Render function, I try to return the jsx element. But instead of the jsx in UseAdvertisementsFilters I get undefined. Most likely the context is lost, but I don't understand why. Help return the jsx from the function.

```
const FilterBydescription = () => {

    const [findByDescription, bindFindByDescription, resetFindByDescription] = useInput('')

    const Render = () => {
        return <FilterInput bind={bindFindByDescription} placeholder={"Find by description"} />;
    };

    return { Render };
}

export function UseAdvertisementsFilters({isLoading}){

    return(
        <aside className="col-xl-3 filter_detail">
            <Row className="filter_detail__wrapper">
                <Col xs={12}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col className={"filter_detail__search"} xs={12}>

                            {/* Get undefined */}
                            {FilterBydescription.Render}

                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Col>  
            </Row>
        </aside>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you're trying to access a function from the `FilterBydescription` function. As you have it right now, `FilterBydescription` isn't a React component. It's a function that returns a `Render` method which renders a React component. So, when trying to access the `Render` property from `FilterBydescription`, you'll get `undefined`.

What you likely want to do is make `FilterBydescription` a component and render that component in your `UseAdvertisementsFilters` component.

Something like this:

```
const FilterByDescription = () => {
  const [
    findByDescription,
    bindFindByDescription,
    resetFindByDescription,
  ] = useInput('');

  return (
    <FilterInput
      bind={bindFindByDescription}
      placeholder={'Find by description'}
    />
  );
};

export function UseAdvertisementsFilters({ isLoading }) {
  return (
    <aside className="col-xl-3 filter_detail">
      <Row className="filter_detail__wrapper">
        <Col xs={12}>
          <Row>
            <Col className={'filter_detail__search'} xs={12}>
              <FilterByDescription />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </aside>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ok, your code works, can you tell me how else I can return the findByDescription value entered in the input from the function. Yes I know I can connect the state via props, but I don't want to render the component unnecessarily while the person is entering characters into the input. How do I get this value from the click of the button.

Comment: If you can provide example code of the rest of your file I'd be happy to help out. I'm not sure where the `useInput` hook is coming from. I can assume what it's doing from the usage but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
const FilterBydescription = () => {
    
        const [findByDescription, bindFindByDescription, resetFindByDescription] = useInput('')
    
    
            return <FilterInput bind={bindFindByDescription} placeholder={"Find by description"} />;
    }
    
    export function UseAdvertisementsFilters({isLoading}){
    
        return(
            <aside className="col-xl-3 filter_detail">
                <Row className="filter_detail__wrapper">
                    <Col xs={12}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col className={"filter_detail__search"} xs={12}>
    
                                {/* Get undefined */}
                                <FilterBydescription />
    
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>  
                </Row>
            </aside>
        )
    }
```